# Having Trouble With GCD and Loading Thumbnails in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code that attempts to load a row of thumbnails in a tableview asynchronously:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalThumbnails; i++)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ^{
        __block GraphicView *graphicView;
        __block Graphic *graphic;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
        ^{
            graphicView = [[tableViewCell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i] retain];
            graphic = [[self.thumbnailCache objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:startingThumbnailIndex + i]] retain];

            if (!graphic)
            {
                graphic = [[self graphicWithType:startingThumbnailIndex + i] retain];
                [self.thumbnailCache setObject: graphic forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:startingThumbnailIndex + i]];
            }

            [graphicView setGraphic:graphic maximumDimension:self.cellDimension];
        });

        [graphicView setNeedsDisplay];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
        ^{
            CGRect graphicViewFrame = graphicView.frame;
            graphicViewFrame.origin.x = ((self.cellDimension - graphicViewFrame.size.width) / 2) + (i * self.cellDimension);
            graphicViewFrame.origin.y = (self.cellDimension - graphicViewFrame.size.height) / 2;
            graphicView.frame = graphicViewFrame;
        });

        [graphicView release];
        [graphic release];
    });

}
```

However when I run the code I get a bad access at this line: `[graphicView setNeedsDisplay];` It's worth mentioning that the code works fine when I have it set up like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalThumbnails; i++)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
        ^{
              //put all the code here
        });
}
```

It works fine and the `UITableView` loads asynchronously when it's first called, however the scrolling is still really choppy.

So I'd like to get the to get the first bit of code to work so I can get the drawing done in the global thread instead of the main thread (which I assume will fix the choppy scrolling?).

Since iOS4 drawing is able to be done asynchronously so I don't believe that is the problem. Possibly I'm misusing the `__Block` type?

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You completely misunderstand how to use GCD. Looking at your code:

```
        __block GraphicView *graphicView;
```

Your variable here is not initialised to nil. It is unsafe to send messages to.

```
        __block Graphic *graphic;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
        ^{
            //statements
        });
```

Your dispatch statement here returns immediately. The system works for you to spin this task off on a different thread. Before, or perhaps at the same time as, the above statements are executed we move on to the next line of execution here...

```
        [graphicView setNeedsDisplay];
```

At this point graphic view may or may not have been initialised by your dispatch statement above. Most likely not as there wont have been time. As it still hasn't been initialised it points to random memory and hence trying to send messages to it causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

If you want to draw cell contents asynchronously (or pre-render images or whatever.) I thouroughly reccommend watching [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) session 211 "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS". They do almost exactly what you seem to be attempting to do and explain all the pitfalls you can run into.

Comment: Thanks for what you wrote and the video was also very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you are trying to re-draw the `UIView` on a working thread. You should move this:

```
[graphicView setNeedsDisplay];
```

To the main queue.